# Error 000725 when running ArcPy toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, arctoolbox

I'm trying to run a script in arcpy and appears the error 000725 "output folder: Dataset C:.. already exists.

The script objective is to clip all shapefiles from a folder by a buffer layer. If the shapefiles clipped are polygons, area is calculated. And I'm trying to export all the Excel tables from these shapefiles with a column called ("NEW_AREA"). I used the `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True`
to fix the error but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

My script:

```
import arcpy
pol = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
buf = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output_buf = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
input_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) 
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
list_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fc = os.listdir(input_folder)

clip_features = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(pol,output_buf,buf)


def CLIP(input_folder, output_folder, clip_features):
    for file in fc:
            for i in fc:
                if i.endswith(".shp"):
                    file = os.path.join(input_folder,i)
                    rename_shp = "clipped_%s" % (i)
                    rename_excel = "calculated%s" % (i)
                    newfile = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_shp)
                    newtable = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_excel)
                    desc = arcpy.Describe(file)
                    geometry = desc.shapeType
                    if geometry == 'Polygon':
                        fieldName = "NEW_AREA"
                        expr ='!shape.area@squaremeters!'
                        arcpy.Clip_analysis(file, clip_features, newfile, "") and arcpy.management.AddField(newfile,"NEW_AREA","DOUBLE") and arcpy.CalculateField_management(newfile,fieldName,expr,'PYTHON') and arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(newfile,newtable,"NEW_AREA")
                    else:
                        arcpy.Clip_analysis(file, clip_features, newfile, "")

CLIP(input_folder, output_folder, clip_features)
```

Comment: There are no Excel files associated with a shapefile. The dBase (`.dbf`) file of a shapefile should be kept well clear of Excel, so you don't accidentally corrupt it.

Comment: That wasn't an answer, it was a comment. Another comment: Your code structure indicates you need to review basic Python coding -- There's no real value in making the main loop inside a function using variables from above; You have a double-nested loop on `fc` which is almost certainly not necessary; The use of `and` after the Clip directive is not best practice, and probably doesn't do what you think it does (can you explain why you're using it?).  Comment out all the `arcpy` code and see if you can make the Python follow your expected flow of control. *Then* start coding the geoprocessing.

Comment: Other issues include no import os statement.  No xls extension on for the output excel table.  "NEW_AREA" in the TableToExcel. Using both ListFeatureClasses and listdir when you only need one method to list the folder content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code could be cleaned up like this.

```
import os #import os was missing
import arcpy
pol = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
buf = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output_buf = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
input_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
clip_features = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(pol,output_buf,buf)

# Only need one of ListFeatureClasses or listdir
list_fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in list_fcs:
    # have a look at the shapefile name
    print(fc)
    rename_shp = "clipped_{}".format(fc)
    # make sure to replace the .shp with a .xls
    rename_excel = "calculated_{}.xls".format(os.path.splitext(fc)[0])
    # have a look at the new names you are going to use for output
    print(rename_shp)
    print(rename_excel)
    newfile = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_shp)
    newtable = os.path.join(output_folder,rename_excel)

    # you are doing the same clip, so move it oustide the if statement
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clip_features, newfile) 
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    geometry = desc.shapeType
    if geometry == 'Polygon':
        fieldName = "NEW_AREA"
        expr ='!shape.area@squaremeters!'
        # remove the anding together of functions
        arcpy.management.AddField(newfile,fieldName,"DOUBLE")
        # if you are using variable for the field name, remove the hard coded "NEW_AREA"
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(newfile,fieldName,expr,'PYTHON')
        # remove the "NEW_AREA" from TableToExcel as this is not  valid parameter value
        arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(newfile,newtable)
```